# Convert fractions into decimal in sql using a function and select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Every time I try to run the following in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I get an error message

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

Is there anyway at all to run this in one statement?

The reason why I'm calling a function in this statement (`dbo.ufn_ConvertJambDepthFractionToNumber`) is because the `dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Overall_Jamb_Depth.InstructionValue AS [Jamb Depth]` column spits out values like 4 1/6", 3 1/4", 6 9/16". I'm using that function to try to convert the `varchar` values (4 1/6", 3 1/4", 6 9/16") into decimals.

If there is a better way to do that, I'm all ears.

```
use BeechworthProdWTS

declare @jamb_depth as varchar

SELECT DISTINCT 
    dbo.QuoteShippingAddress.Name AS [CDS Location],
    dbo.QuoteShippingAddress.Address1 AS [Quote Shipping Address1], 
    dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Overall_Jamb_Depth.InstructionValue AS [Jamb Depth], 
    dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Count_view.Doors, 
    dbo.CDS_Shipments_Screen_Count_view.Screens, 
    dbo.CDS_Shipments_Windows_Count_view.Windows, 
    dbo.LineItemMaster.LineNumber,
    @jamb_depth = dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Overall_Jamb_Depth.InstructionValue, 
    dbo.ufn_ConvertJambDepthFractionToNumber(@jamb_depth)
FROM   
    dbo.Quotes 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.QuoteShippingAddress WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Quotes.QuoteID = dbo.QuoteShippingAddress.QuoteID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Clients WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Quotes.ClientID = dbo.Clients.ClientID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CustomerProjectInformation WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Quotes.QuoteID = dbo.CustomerProjectInformation.QuoteID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.LineItemMaster WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Quotes.QuoteID = dbo.LineItemMaster.QuoteID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.LineItems WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.LineItemMaster.LineItemMasterID = dbo.LineItems.LineItemMasterID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.WorkOrders WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.LineItems.LineItemID = dbo.WorkOrders.LineItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Count_view WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.LineItems.LineItemID = dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Count_view.LineItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Overall_Jamb_Depth WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.LineItems.LineItemID = dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Overall_Jamb_Depth.LineItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.CDS_Shipments_Screen_Count_view WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.LineItems.LineItemID = dbo.CDS_Shipments_Screen_Count_view.LineItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.CDS_Shipments_Windows_Count_view WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.LineItems.LineItemID = dbo.CDS_Shipments_Windows_Count_view.LineItemID
```

Comment: You need to decide whether you want to return data to the client or to assign a value to a variable.

Comment: While you are pondering that decision you might want to read about NOLOCK. It has a LOT of "benefits" that most people either ignore or are not aware of. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ I would also suggest using aliases so your queries are not a wall of text. And three part naming in the field list has been deprecated.

Comment: No. You can't do both at the same time. The error message really can't be any clearer on that. And if it could be done you would have another issue to deal with here. You are using a scalar variable and assigning the value to a select query. Which row from the select statement do you want in your variable??

Comment: `declare @jamb_depth as varchar` - that's a **BIG NO-NO !!** You should **always** provide an **explicit length** to your `varchar` - otherwise, as in this case, you end up with a variable of **exactly ONE character** in length -  which is typically **NOT** what you want. ***ALWAYS*** define a length - use `declare @jamb_depth as varchar(100)` (or whatever makes sense here)

Comment: @marc_s, thank you for the note. i'm pretty new to SQL. pretty much everything has been self-taught. i'll definitely remember that for future.

Comment: @SeanLange, Understood. The main thing I'm trying to do is convert or cast or something dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Overall_Jamb_Depth.InstructionValue AS [Jamb Depth] to a decimal. That column spits out as 4 1/6", 3 1/4", 6 9/16". What would be a better way to convert or cast that to a decimal?

Comment: I would convert the scalar function to an inline table valued function. It is more flexible and faster than a scalar function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are pretty new to SQL I reformatted this using aliases so you can see how much difference it make visually. This doesn't affect performance but it does keep the developer sane. Also, not really sure what you are trying to do with your scalar but maybe trying to get the value for each row?

Cleaned up your query might look something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    qsa.Name AS [CDS Location],
    qsa.Address1 AS [Quote Shipping Address1], 
    sdojd.InstructionValue AS [Jamb Depth], 
    sdcv.Doors, 
    sscv.Screens, 
    swcv.Windows, 
    lim.LineNumber,
    --@jamb_depth = sdojd.InstructionValue, --not really sure what you are trying to do here
    --dbo.ufn_ConvertJambDepthFractionToNumber(@jamb_depth)
    JambDepth = dbo.ufn_ConvertJambDepthFractionToNumber(sdojd.InstructionValue)
FROM dbo.Quotes q
INNER JOIN dbo.QuoteShippingAddress qsa ON q.QuoteID = qsa.QuoteID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Clients c ON q.ClientID = c.ClientID 
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerProjectInformation cpi ON q.QuoteID = cpi.QuoteID 
INNER JOIN dbo.LineItemMaster lim ON q.QuoteID = lim.QuoteID 
INNER JOIN dbo.LineItems li ON lim.LineItemMasterID = li.LineItemMasterID 
INNER JOIN dbo.WorkOrders wo ON li.LineItemID = wo.LineItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Count_view sdcv ON li.LineItemID = sdcv.LineItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CDS_Shipments_Door_Overall_Jamb_Depth sdojd ON li.LineItemID = sdojd.LineItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CDS_Shipments_Screen_Count_view sscv ON li.LineItemID = sscv.LineItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CDS_Shipments_Windows_Count_view swcv ON li.LineItemID = swcv.LineItemID
```